# Capture group reference + numeral

Tags: regex

For example, I would like to replace a string by the first capture group, with a `1` appended to it.

I would like to do `$11` (interpreted as `$1` and `1`), but this does not work on every flavour.

What should I do instead?

Comment: which flavor are you using?

Comment: @rock321987 I'm using `.NET` flavour, but I would like to know the answer to as many flavours as possible.

Comment: @Tushar I'm not sure if you have heard of it before, but [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina).

Comment: @Tushar For your information, I come from [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: *Under the hood, it uses .NET's regex engine, which means that both the .NET flavour and the ECMAScript flavour are available* - Use `${1}1` to replace with the first backreference and `1`, use `${11}` to replace with the 11th backreference

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is an answer

Comment: I was looking for a tag - there is no retina tag on SO...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's because Retina is a golfing language (esolang).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The info at the [Retina link](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina) you provided says:

> Under the hood, it uses **.NET's regex engine**, which means that **both the .NET flavour and the ECMAScript flavour** are available.

So, if you are using the .NET flavor, use `${1}1` to replace with the first backreference and `1`, use `${11}` or `$11` to replace with the 11th backreference.

If you are using an ECMAScript expression, `$11` will be treated this way: if there are fewer than 11 capture groups, but there is 1, `$1` will be parsed as the backreference to Group 1 followed with a literal `1`; if there are 11 capture groups, it will be a backreference to the 11th group.