# Capture group + numeral for PHP

Tags: php, regex, capture-group

I referred this question - [Capture group reference + numeral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940636/capture-group-reference-numeral)

I tried with both the options provided there. Here is example code using ECMAScript expression (I guess I need to use this, correct me if I am wrong) -

```
$string = "box.last_rollout_revision = dummy";

$regex = "/(box\.last_rollout_revision[\s]*=[\s]*)[a-z0-9-_]*([\n]*)/";

$test = "234";
$replacementPattern = "$1".$test."$2";

echo preg_replace($regex,$replacementPattern,$string);
```

**Expected output**

```
box.last_rollout_revision = 234
```

**Actual getting**

```
34
```

P.S. I am trying to replace value against a key in a config file which has several other key-value pairs. I think regex will make it easier in this case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the replacement pattern to

```
$replacementPattern = '${1}'.$test.'$2';
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Q0fJZm)

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath Just to explain - your `$replacementPattern` ended up like `$1234$2` making it search for capture group no. `1234`.

Comment: @Wiktor when I try the same on http://phptester.net/, it gives me the output - `abc`, with a notice - `NOTICE Undefined variable: 1 on line number 8`

Comment: Just tested and it obtained `box.last_rollout_revision = 234`